# Set theory - Relations, equivalence relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $X = \{1,2,3\}$ then a partition of $C$ of $X$ could be $\{\{1\},\{2,3\}\}$. Correct?

Does this partition equal the relation $\{(1,1),(2,3),(2,2),(3,3),(3,2)\}$ is this an equivalence relation?
Does the set of equivalence classes $= \{\{1\},\{2,3\}\}$?

Sorry I just trying to understand the relationship between equivalence relations and partitions.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Yes.  The elements in each tuple belong to the same partition.

Answer (score 1):

Partitions and equivalence relations on a set $X$ *determine* each other, but they are *not equal*.
Other than that, your example is correct.

Comment: Thank you, I'm beginning to understand it now!

Comment: Does every set induce an equivalence relation?

Comment: How do you mean it?